# Vuejs v-on:mouseover not working to show menu

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a menu show up when I place my mouse over a LI tag.

It works with a simple variable, when I use

```html
@mouseover="hoverFormsControls=true" @mouseleave="hoverFormsControls=false"
```

This is working, but when I change to an array, like this

```html
@mouseover="hovers[0]=true" @mouseleave="hovers[0]=false"
```

It doesn´t works anymore.

The variable `hoverFormsControls` starts with false
This array (hovers) starts with all positions false.

I expect to, when I hover my mouse over that element, his child element would be visible, but it's not working with the array, only with the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [`reactivity caveat`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), so you should do :

```
 @mouseover="$set(hovers,0,true)" @mouseleave="$set(hovers,0,false)"
```